# How to set Min and Max date for Google timline Charts [2020]

Tags: javascript, date, charts, google-visualization, timeline

I would like to set the Min and Max date in Google timeline charts.
I have tried :

```
var options = {
    height: 450,
    timeline: {
      groupByRowLabel: true
    },
    legend: 'none',
    tooltip: {isHtml: true},

     hAxis: {
        minValue : new Date(2018, 11, 31),
        maxValue : new Date(2020, 1, 3)
      },
  };
```

As you see, i see 2015 so it doesn't work :

[image]

Someone said in another post:

you can use options --> hAxis.minValue & hAxis.maxValue

I thought that's what I was doing. How to do?

Here is my code :

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['timeline'],'language': 'fr'});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
        data.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'dummy bar label' });
        data.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'tooltip' });
        data.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
        data.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
        data.addRows([
          [ 'Washington', null, 'George', new Date(2015, 3, 29), new Date(2018, 2, 3) ],
           [ 'Washington', null, 'George', new Date(2018, 3, 29), new Date(2020, 2, 3) ],
          [ 'Adams', null, 'John', new Date(2019, 2, 3),  new Date(2020, 2, 3) ],
          [ 'Jefferson', null, 'Thomas', new Date(2018, 2, 3),  new Date(2020, 2, 3) ]]);



      var options = {
        height: 450,
        timeline: {
          groupByRowLabel: true
        },
        legend: 'none',
        tooltip: {isHtml: true},

         hAxis: {
            minValue : new Date(2018, 11, 31),
            maxValue : new Date(2020, 1, 3)
          },
      };



      var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

options `hAxis.minValue` & `hAxis.maxValue` only work to expand the x-axis.
where `hAxis.minValue` is less than the earliest date in the data table,
and `hAxis.maxValue` is greater than the latest date in the data table.

they will not reduce the x-axis within the dates that exist in the data table.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['timeline'],
  language: 'fr'
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
  data.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'dummy bar label' });
  data.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'tooltip' });
  data.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
  data.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
  data.addRows([
    [ 'Washington', null, 'George', new Date(2015, 3, 29), new Date(2018, 2, 3) ],
    [ 'Washington', null, 'George', new Date(2018, 3, 29), new Date(2020, 2, 3) ],
    [ 'Adams', null, 'John', new Date(2019, 2, 3),  new Date(2020, 2, 3) ],
    [ 'Jefferson', null, 'Thomas', new Date(2018, 2, 3),  new Date(2020, 2, 3) ]
  ]);
  
  var options = {
    height: 450,
    timeline: {
      groupByRowLabel: true
    },
    legend: 'none',
    tooltip: {isHtml: true},
    hAxis: {
      minValue: new Date(2010, 11, 31),
      maxValue: new Date(2030, 1, 3)
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: To understand yes!

But, it is possible to reduce the x-axis within the dates that exist in the data table ?

I want to be able to manage year by year and we won't see others years.

Comment: the only way is to change the data used to draw the chart...