# How to use google chart timeline component - present all time in same row, present overlapping timelines also on the same row so it will overlay?

Tags: reactjs, charts, timeline

The timeline chart is giving option to groupByRow but once two tasks have the same dates this row is splitted for upper and lower one. I don't want this bevahiour I would like them to be stacked.
Also how to modify hAxis values max and min in timeline

I tried: groupByRow, isStacked: true didn't work.
also hAxis any values max mini gridlines don't work with timeline component.

Comment: for min and max `hAxis`, use options: `hAxis: {minValue: minDate, maxValue: maxDate}` -- see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65131484/5090771) for details. - the timeline chart does not support stacking